# UI Tests no longer working on Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcode-bots, xcode7.3

I have a set of XCUITests that run with our iOS app. They used to run fine on Xcode 7.2.1, but upgrading to 7.3 causes tests to fail in the "Set Up -> Wait for app to idle" phase with the following error:

`UI Testing Failure - Failed to perform AX action for monitoring the animations of <XCUIApplicationProcess: 0x7f82450288c0 [appName here] (25670)>, error: Error -25204 performing AXAction 2043`

This failure is seen on every single UI test, both on bots and when running locally.

Has anyone else seen this or have any workarounds?

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue as well

Comment: Also having this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note to self: Don't have code that crashes your app on purpose while tests are trying to run. D:

Basically there was a call to terminate the app within the launch phase of the app for a certain scheme (in our case, the TEST scheme). Be thorough in checking what the app is doing when it launches for testing, because there might be errant behavior.

Comment: I have this problem, but not this solution.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone still has this issue - for me it was activating the Optimizely framework that caused this error. Disabling the framework when running XCUITest solved it for me.

Comment: Any idea specifically what this framework was doing that caused the error?